# C- fprintf two variables in same line

Tags: c, printf

I'm printing this:

```
char aulaIP2[50];
char aula[50];

printf("Enter the name of classroom: ");
fgets(aula, 49, stdin);
if (fgets(aula, sizeof aula, stdin)){
        printf("Enter IP classroom: ");
        fgets(aulaIP2, 49, stdin);
        FILE *file = fopen("aules.text", "w+");
        fprintf(file, "%s:%s", aula, aulaIP2);
        fclose(file);
        getchar();
}
```

and the output in the file is:

```
306
:127
```

and I want:

```
306:127
```

Why isn't `fprintf` able to print that in the same line? I have already tried doing it with two `fprintf`s but it's the same result.

Comment: That code should not be producing that result, period.  You need to make a minimal testcase: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Something tells me these two strings may have been read from a file. (A leading/terminating hard return *could* explain it.)

Comment: @MooingDuck what if `aulaIP2` was `"\b \n127"` or something similar?

Comment: look at the mod ive done

Comment: Here is how you use your code: run program, type "306" *and then Return* ... get it?

Comment: from the fgets documentation: "A newline character makes fgets stop reading, but it is considered a valid character by the function and included in the string copied to str." So your strings have newline characters in them. (don't know why the `:` is dissappearing though, oh it isn't.)

Comment: : is printed, i forgot adding it here

Comment: @clcto: Hey, the question changed, the colon wasn't in the observed output beforehand.  That's not fair.

Comment: @MooingDuck i know it was changed. My question was about the original. Can't you use `\b` to go back in the buffer (depending on the output terminal)?

Comment: @clcto: Fair point.  Windows cmd won't do that, but bash or other outputs might.

Comment: Voting to reopen now that the output is correctly transcribed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [`fgets`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/) documentation:

> A newline character makes fgets stop reading, but it is considered a valid character by the function and included in the string copied to str.

So when you read in your strings, they actually contain the newline character, which is then printed as part of the string. Instead of using `fgets()` use `scanf()` which will read until the first whitespace (and not including):

```
 scanf( "%50s", aula );
```

Comment: `scanf("%50s", aula)` will read a whitespace-delimited word. If you want to read a line of text, use `fgets` and then remove the `'\n'` character if it's there.

Answer (score 0):

According to http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fprintf/ fprintf is able to print in one line. See the example on the bottom of that page.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    char* aula = "306";
    char* aulaIP2 = "127";

    FILE* file = fopen("aules.text", "ab+");
    fprintf(file, "%s:%s", aula, aulaIP2);
    fclose(file);

    return 0;
}
```

When I read `aules.text`, I see:

```
306:127
```

Are `aula` and `aulaIP2` actually strings, or were you trying to write integers instead (%d)?

Comment: That does not explain the multi-line output nor the disappearing colon.

Comment: @Jongware: The *original* post (http://stackoverflow.com/posts/23665061/revisions) did not contain enough information to show where the sources were from. This code was provided to prove that, with the construct of the variables given, this SHOULD give the `306:127` that was expected. The error had to have come from somewhere else, such as the values contained within `aula` or `aulaIP2`.

Comment: True, but the number of *possible* ways the OP could have gotten that wrong output is so large, I thought it safer to wait for an explanation. You can write any number of programs that "work correctly" for the given (expected) output.